# Call a global filter from a method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

I have a global filter I am using from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuejs-community/vue-filter-date-format to format a date that I can call from the html like so:

```
{{new Date(VALUE) | dateFormat('MMM. DD, YYYY', dateFormatConfig)}}
```

I am trying to call this from a method. This is how Vuejs says to call it.

```
this.$options.filters.FILTERNAME(VALUE)
```

But I do not know how to make this work. This does not work because there is no VALUE

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat('MMM. DD, YYYY', dateFormatConfig)
```

I have also tried this:

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat('MMM. DD, YYYY', VALUE)
```

and this:

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat(VALUE, 'MMM. DD, YYYY')
```

and this:

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat('MMM. DD, YYYY', dateFormatConfig)(VALUE)
```

None of these work. Does anyone know how to call this properly from a method?

**UPDATE:**

Turns out this does work:

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat(VALUE, 'MMM. DD, YYYY')
```

I needed to convert the VALUE to this: `new Date(VALUE)`

So the end result is:

```
this.$options.filters.dateFormat(new Date(VALUE), 'MMM. DD, YYYY')
```

Comment: I haven't done much with filters.  If no one solves your problem here, I recommend going to the npm link you posted, clicking the github repository link, and then clicking on the contributor Eduard.  He has an email listed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*This does not work because there is no VALUE*", apparently you have `new Date(VALUE)` in the HTML version.

Comment: @TJ I replaced the actual value with VALUE for stackover. The HTML version works great. I would like to call this from a method.

Comment: @Tim I was able to get in touch with the developer. See my update above. Thank you

Comment: @Jason Glad that the developer was able to help.  If your problem is solved, you might want to create a new answer from your question update, and accept the answer.  That way other people know that the problem is resolved, and can find your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your filter registration.In your index.js(main app file), you should import as `import VueFilterDateFormat from '@vuejs-community/vue-filter-date-format';` and then `Vue.use(VueFilterDateFormat);`
or you can register it locally in some components.
Then you will be able to use it as the basic usage indicates
[[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuejs-community/vue-filter-date-format)]

Comment: I have registered it exactly that way and I am able to use it in its basic way. I think you misunderstood my issue. I am trying to call the filter from a method not the HTML

Comment: Sorry for that. Filters are usually used for html pre-render.
You should use utils for that, or a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment for your case

Comment: Agreed however, moment's website is telling us to quite using them :/